# Auto generate images using uploaded files

Tags: iunknown

I've to create a bunch of jpeg images which have the same template with just a few components that change depending on the user. 
I want to know what is the best software/language to use to make this?

For example:
I have to generate a 2443x2443 jpeg. Only the name and profile description will change. These changes will be supplied by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language you use depends entirely on what you are trying to accomplish. If you are working on a website, then you might consider a language like php, and use some of the functions it provides like [imagestring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) that turns a string into an image. If you are making a desktop application, then most of the popular languages will have image manipulation libraries that let you work with images.